# what is the geometry interpretation of fractional differintegral?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory

By some analogy, the integral and differential can be extend to factorial differintegral, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differintegral

My question is, what is the he geometry interpretation of fractional differintegral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you [I.Podlubny Geometric and Physical Interpretation of Fractional Integration and Fractional Differentiation](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0110241)